# How to make JPA create tables using JAVA SE and Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

Im creating a simple Java SE application but I have a problem configuring JPA with Tomcat 8.0.38. Is it possible to automatically generate the schema using these technologies?

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="postgres" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>co.entity.Pais</class>
    <class>co.entity.PilaEntity</class>
    <class>co.entity.PilaNovedad</class>
    <class>co.entity.PilaPago</class>
    <class>co.entity.PilaRisk</class>
    <class>co.entity.PilaSuperEntity</class>
    <class>co.edu.entity.PilaUser</class>
    <class>co.edu.entity.PilaUserIntermediary</class>
    <class>co.edu.entity.PilaUserSuperEntity</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"     value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/pila" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"     value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect"    value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>PilaPayments</groupId>
  <artifactId>PilaPayments</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-entity-filtering -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Console log when starting tomcat from eclipse

```
nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule    begin
ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting    property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:PilaPayments' did not find a      matching property.
nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.38
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener    log
 INFORMACIÓN: Server built:          Oct 6 2016 20:51:55 UTC
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: Server number:         8.0.38.0
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: OS Name:               Windows 7
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: OS Version:            6.1
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: Architecture:          amd64
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-b15
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software    Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software    Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache    Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache     Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Program Files\Apache   Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\wtpwebapps
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program     Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener    lifecycleEvent
 INFORMACIÓN: La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que   permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en     java.library.path: C:\Program   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Window      s;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/client;C:/Program Files      (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin;C:/Program Files    (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program     Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program    Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common     Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common    Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows    Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32     \WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows     Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-    Static;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files     (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows     Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL    Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-    Static;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft      SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL     Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program      Files\nodejs\;D:\Software\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program      Files\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program       Files\Perforce\DVCS\;C:\Program      Files\Git\cmd;c:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roami     ng\npm;D:\Software\eclipse;;.
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:46 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool    getSharedSelector
 INFORMACIÓN: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:46 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool    getSharedSelector
 INFORMACIÓN: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
 INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 2147 ms
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio Catalina
nov 07, 2016 5:22:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.38
nov 07, 2016 5:22:50 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMACIÓN: Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no     contenía TLDs. Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una    completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs.     Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora    de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
 nov 07, 2016 5:22:51 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase     createSecureRandom
INFORMACIÓN: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation      using [SHA1PRNG] took [108] milliseconds.
nov 07, 2016 5:22:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files\Apache Software     Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs de la aplicación web
nov 07, 2016 5:22:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig   deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache    Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs has finished in 49 ms
nov 07, 2016 5:22:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files\Apache Software     Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager de la aplicación web
nov 07, 2016 5:22:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig   deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache      Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager has finished in 129 ms
nov 07, 2016 5:22:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig  deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files\Apache Software    Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT de la aplicación web
nov 07, 2016 5:22:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT has finished in 40 ms
nov 07, 2016 5:22:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
nov 07, 2016 5:22:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
nov 07, 2016 5:22:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 6154 ms
```

At startup it only deploys the war but it doesn't create the schema

Comment: Show us the code ?

Comment: I added some code @javaguy, please tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: do you have any error  ? Can you post some logs ?

Comment: @Massimo, It doesn't show any errors, servers starts fine but as you see it doesnt' create the schema.

Comment: It doesn't seem to deploy anything other than the default ROOT, manager, and docs app of tomcat. Check that your application is indeed deployed. I don't really see how that is possible.

Comment: My app uses jersey for JAX-RS, I called a mock ws and it answered so I dont know what is going on.

Comment: Have you create a SessionFactory somewhere? Because that's where Hibernate will start doing something (read the persistence.xml, etc.).